# Interactive Map Drill-down ability in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
State<-c("Alabama","Alabama","Alaska","Alaska")
StateCode<-c("AL","AL","AK","AK")
County<-c("AUTAUGA","BALDWIN","ANCHORAGE","BETHEL")
CountyCode<-c("AL001","AL003","AK020","AK050")
Murder<-c(5,6,7,8)
d<-data.frame(State,StateCode,County,CountyCode, Num)



State StateCode    County CountyCode Num
1 Alabama        AL   AUTAUGA      AL001   5
2 Alabama        AL   BALDWIN      AL003   6
3  Alaska        AK ANCHORAGE      AK020   7
4  Alaska        AK    BETHEL      AK050   8
```

I have been searching for an option between R packages to create a drill-down map from State to County level out of this but I can't find a working example with code anywhere. Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLZLKB) Any feedback on this?

Comment: you are looking for an R packlage that contains  a mapping from State to County?

Comment: yes, when you click on the state it should break to county level. Basically a working example

Comment: what do you mean by "click on"?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLZLKB

Comment: I see, you want to replicate this map with R and some additional data. I would suggest editing the question.